# Replacing my /home drive with a new drive

Tags: mount, home-directory, fstab

My "/home" sits on a separate drive, but that drive is getting full. I bought a new larger HDD and installed it. I copied my whole "/home" to the new drive and then changed the "UUID" in "/etc/fstab" to the new drive. I restarted the system and when I tried to login it failed. In tty when I login it states "no /home". I had to change the fstab config back to the original "UUID" of the old HDD to be able to login normally.

I was thinking that it would be as simple as changing the "UUID" to the new drive in the fstab config, but I was mistaken. I can't find any guidance on replacing the drive where "/home" sits, if someone could help or point me to something.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo blkid -c /dev/null` and `cat /etc/fstab`. BTW how exactly did you copy the original `/home` to the new drive?

Comment: Your basic approach seems OK.  After you update the fstab do a `sudo mount -a` to make sure everything is OK, no need to reboot yet.  It sounds like you left the old drive in, did you change fstab to mount it at a different mountpoint?

Comment: Organic Marble&steeldriver - so, got it to work. I did a "cp -p" to preserve, but i used kyodake copy flags (-ax) then edited the fstab and "mount -a" and all is good. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Suppose the old home is /dev/sdc1 and de new home is /dev/sdd1

Open a terminal and run:

```
exec sudo -i
mkdir /media/hometemp
mount /dev/sdd1 /media/hometemp
cd /home
cp -ax . /media/hometemp
cd /
mv /home /home.old
mkdir /home
mount /dev/sdd1 /home
exit
```

If everything works, change the UUID in /etc/fstab to /dev/sdd1.

Comment: Thank you, I used your copy ( I only used -p flag) and it mounted fine.